# Parse the arguments of a git rebase command to determine the upstream, if one is specified

Tags: git, bash, shell, rebase

I'm trying to do this:

1. User runs `git rebase-like [same arguments as rebase]`
2. The script

   1. determines the `upstream` if one is specified
   2. pulls out other select options from the command
   3. does stuff
   4. then passes the original arguments on to `rebase`

This question is about 2.1 and 2.2. I expect the most reliable way to do this would be parsing with Git. But for now I'm taking a more manual command line parsing approach. Maybe you can think of a nice regex, or some bash cleverness?

(I've tried reading `git-rebase` source working back from `$switch_to`, and `git-rebase--merge` source working back from `$base` but I'm fairly new to shell scripts and can't tell whether there's a smallish piece of the source I could use.)

Here's what I have so far. It's limited: it's stricter about the order of arguments than `git-rebase` is. If `[ <upstream> [<branch]]` is used, it has to be at the end of the command. I can determine the specified upstream for

```
git rebase [...] --onto <newbase> [...]
```

and for

```
git rebase <upstream> [<branch]
```

but not for

```
git rebase <upstream> [<branch>] ...
```

My script is not beautiful, and it's a brittle. I'd really like a way to get this more directly with Git. At the least I'd like to upgrade my script so it accepts arguments in any order. Ideas?

```bash
# !/bin/bash

NEWBASE QUIET UPSTREAM branch
# the "environment" for those env vars is the command line input
# I'm open to hearing arguments for lowercasing them

options () {
    local onto_index
    for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
      case "${!i}" in
        "--onto")
          newbase_index=$((i+1))
          NEWBASE="${!newbase_index}"
          ;;
        "-q"|"--quiet") QUIET=-q ;;
      esac
    done
}

opt_with_arg () {
    [[ \
        "$1" == "--fork" \
        || "$1" == "--onto" \
        || "$1" == "-s" \
        || "$1" == "-X" \
        || "$1" == "-x" \
        || "$1" == "-exec" \
    ]] \
    || [[ "$1" == "--root" ]]
    # though --root doesn't actually have an argument, including it here
    # is shorter than checking `opt_with_arg $1 || [[ $1 == "--root" ]]`
}

options "$@"

if [[ -n "$1" && "${!#}" != "-"* ]]; then
    [[ $# -gt 3 ]] && shift "$(($#-3))"
    opt_with_arg "$1" && shift 2
    [[ -n "$3" ]] && shift
    opt_with_arg "$1" && shift 2
    [[ "$1" == "-"* ]] && shift
    UPSTREAM="$1"
    #
    # possibilites after first shift:
    # (uppercase is what we want to preserve, lowercase we want to cut,
    # u is <upstream>, b is <branch>, x is <someoption>.)
    #    U,
    #    U B, X U, --root b, --opt_with_arg n,
    #    X U B, X X U, x --root b, x --opt_with_arg n, --opt_with_arg N U, --opt_with_arg n x
    # possibilites after second shift: U,
    #    U B, X U, x
    #    X U B, X X U, x --root b, x --opt_with_arg n
    # possibilites after third shift:
    #    U, x
    #    U B, X U, --root b, --opt_with_arg n
    # possibilites after fourth shift:
    #    U, x
    #    U B, X U
    # possibilites after fifth shift:
    #    U, U B
fi

branch="${NEWBASE:=$UPSTREAM}"
```

Comment: Because the "base branch" may have moved on to new commits since you branched off of it, would it be sufficient for you to get the Commit SHA of the common root between the two, or do you actually need to know the branch name itself?

Comment: To clarify: you're really just trying to parse the argument looking for the _new base_...  This doesn't actually have anything to do with git at all, you're just trying to parse the command line?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you mean by "base branch". Rebase is going to copy certain commits. The arguments to `git rebase` determine: (1) which commits to copy, using assistance from the current `HEAD` or an argument; (2) the commit that gets `git checkout`-ed to serve as HEAD during the copying. In any case when it's done the current branch (if any) is the one that is re-set (`git update-ref`-ed, really) to the final copied commit. Which of these are you looking for?

Comment: @dillius the branch name itself

Comment: @EdwardThomson at a minimum I'd like to be able to handle `git rebase <upstream> -x`. that could be a question of command line parsing. but ideally I'd like a way of determining this directly in git. (my full script watches for quiet in the thing I've called onto here. I see now that that would be confusing --in my above example there's no reason to treat have that first function. I'll update my example)

Comment: @torek the branch at (2) in cases when what the user provided was a branch name (not in cases when the user provided a commit sha). e.g. in `git rebase master`, I want `master`. maybe the "target" branch is better? I've seen both used. I've added a clarifying note to my question

Comment: Ah. The rebase documentation itself just calls this `upstream` unless there is an `--onto`, and it's always: the explicitly named `--onto` argument if there is one; the explicitly given `<upstream>` if there is one; or the computed `<upstream>` if none was specified. The last is just `@{upstream}`, parsed with `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` (and you can do the same for an explicit `--onto` or `<upstream>`).

Comment: @torek cool so then I'm trying to get the upstream's name, if it's been specified, without doing the rebase

Comment: ... in which case, I think you need to duplicate `git rebase`'s options parsing, at least to a limited extent. Note that `--fork-point` does not affect the chosen upstream and has no arguments (it affects instead the set of commits to copy).

Comment: @torek yeah that's what I'm thinking but there's so much going on there, and I'm new enough to shell scripting that it would take me longer to fully understand `git-rebase` than this particular project is worth! btw I've rewritten the question, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://www.git-scm.com/docs/api-parse-options

Comment: @DylanYoung Wow throwback! Funny to see that old code. Will have to dig around and see what exactly I was trying to do. Hadn't seen api-parse-options before, thanks! Certainly _sounds_ like it would be helpful

Comment: @henry I think api-parse-options has all the functionality; it's just not super easy to use being a c-api.  It'd be nice if someone wrote a wrapper around it for scripting.  Add it to my endless list of possible future projects I guess, lol.  It would be so convenient for aliases and external commands though.

Comment: You could also look at `rev-parse --parseopt`, which I think exposes some of this API, but it's pretty limited (didn't do what I wanted, that's for sure).  Seems limited to normalization rather than actual extraction.

Answer (score 0):

Two new documentation elements can help inform your bash options parsing script:

First: revs come first before the pathspec among command line arguments, but Git documentation did not spell out that dashed options come before other args, which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit c11f950](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c11f95010cc9f09ea3e5d401bc14c9b6663d2893) (17 Jan 2022) by [Teng Long (`dyrone`)](https://github.com/dyrone).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e704a44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e704a4486ed715661423adabcb9d75c729059a41), 09 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-cli.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c11f95010cc9f09ea3e5d401bc14c9b6663d2893): clarify "options first and then args"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Teng Long</sup>

> There are some commands permit the user whether to provide options first before args, or the reverse order.
> For example:
>
> ```
> git push --dry-run <remote> <ref>
> ```
>
> And:
>
> ```
> git push <remote> <ref> --dry-run
> ```
>
> Both of them is supported, but some commands do not, for instance:
>
> ```
> git ls-remote --heads <remote>
> ```
>
> And:
>
> ```
> git ls-remote <remote> --heads
> ```
>
> If `<remote>` only has one ref and it's name is "`refs/heads/--heads`", you will get the same result, otherwise will not.
> This is because the former in the second example will parse "`--heads`" as an "`option`" which means to limit to only "refs/heads" when listing the remote references, the latter treat "`--heads`" as an argument which means to filter the result list with the given pattern.
>
> Therefore, we want to specify a bit more in "`gitcli.txt`" about the way we recommend and help to resolve the ambiguity around some git command usage.
> See [related disscussions](https://public-inbox.org/git/cover.1642129840.git.dyroneteng@gmail.com/).

`gitcli` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c11f95010cc9f09ea3e5d401bc14c9b6663d2893/Documentation/gitcli.txt#L22-L30):

> Options come first and then args.
> A subcommand may take dashed options (which may take their own
> arguments, e.g. "`--max-parents 2`") and arguments.
>
> You SHOULD
> give dashed options first and then arguments.
>
> Some commands may
> accept dashed options after you have already gave non-option
> arguments (which may make the command ambiguous), but you should
> not rely on it (because eventually we may find a way to fix
> these ambiguity by enforcing the "options then args" rule).

And, still with Git 2.36:

See [commit 518e15d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/518e15db742ee58e73d486251c67218c6a0fa4f5) (20 Jan 2022) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e66e990](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e66e9906e644ada571a6fd1e044503d292850574), 11 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`parse-options`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/518e15db742ee58e73d486251c67218c6a0fa4f5): document bracketing of argh
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

[`parse-options.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/518e15db742ee58e73d486251c67218c6a0fa4f5/parse-options.h#L84-L92)

```
 * `argh`::
 *   token to explain the kind of argument this option wants. Does not
 *   begin in capital letter, and does not end with a full stop.
 *   Should be wrapped by N_() for translation.
 *   Is automatically enclosed in brackets when printed, unless it
 *   contains any of the following characters: ()<>[]|
 *   E.g. "name" is shown as "<name>" to indicate that a name value
 *   needs to be supplied, not the literal string "name", but
 *   "<start>,<end>" and "(this|that)" are printed verbatim.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is going to be getopts. Rebase is a big grab-bag of configurable tools and options for history surgery with hunk shuffling galore, so "simplest" is both desperately needed and relative here.  Here's a starter kit to give you the idea of handling the different cases, it passes a smoketest.

edit: to make it scan options wherever they are

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# use getopts to scan/skip options and their args,
# first separate arg that isn’t an optarg is an explicit upstream

unset upstream

while (( OPTIND <= $# )); do
    # skip non-option args, set upstream on first one
    while [[ ${@:$OPTIND:1} != -* ]]; do
        [[ ! -v upstream ]] && upstream=`git rev-parse "${@:$OPTIND:1}"`
        (( ++OPTIND > $# )) && break
    done

    # scan options+args, remember options we care about
    while getopts ?qvnfms:x:X:C:ir-: opt; do
        case $opt in
            \?) set -x ;; # for debugging this script, real rebase will choke on it
            f)  echo noticed the -f option go by ;;
            -)  case $OPTARG in
                    root) echo noticed the --root option go by ;;
                    *=*) ;;
                    onto|exec|empty|strategy|strategy-option|whitespace) let ++OPTIND ;;
                esac
                ;;
        esac
    done
done

[[ ! -v upstream ]] && upstream=`git rev-parse @{upstream}`

# your pre-rebase stuff here, then

git rebase "$@"
```

Comment: Neat thanks! More advanced than I was then, but this isn't a pattern I seen yet. I'm trying to remember what I was trying to do. Will test this if I remember